# AddHandler line doesn't compile

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, events, handler

Trying to change following C# code to VB.NET in my `ICommand` implementation:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Here's the equivalent `add` method in VB.NET:

```
<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)> _
AddHandler(ByVal value As PropertyChangedEventHandler)
  propchanged = DirectCast([Delegate].Combine(propchanged, value), PropertyChangedEventHandler)

  AddHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
End AddHandler
```

The last line `AddHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value` throws compile-time error saying that *Value of type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler' cannot be converted to 'System.EventHandler'*. Why? Also, why doesn't `PropertyChangedEventHandler` derive from `EventHandler`? What would fix the above line?

Comment: Seems like the problem might be with the calling code, not the code you've shown above.

Comment: @slugster: As I said, it throws a compile-time error, not run-time, so problem cannot possibly be at calling code end.

Comment: You've defined the type of `CanExecuteChanged` as `EventHandler` - so either your definition is wrong and it should be `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, or if you're sure you've got it right then the **calling code** needs to cast/convert its `PropertyChangedEventHandler` to an `EventHandler` before calling.

Comment: @slugster: Thanks a bunch. Your tip helped me see what I was missing. It wasn't the calling code, it was just that I was using wrong type for my event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delegates do not follow inheritance, so PropertyChangedEventHandler & EventHandler are two different thing which can not be used to reference each other.

secondly the C# code you've shown is for CanExecuteChanged/RequerySuggested, but the vb code looks for PropertyChanged event

so as a suggestion, the conversion of the c# code in question to VB.net would be

```vb
<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)> _
AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
    AddHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
End AddHandler
```

above is just a guess assuming the AddHandler method is for CanExecuteChanged, you may need to adjust accordingly

perhaps a full implementation would be

```vb
Public Custom Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        AddHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        RemoveHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
    End RemoveHandler
End Event
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This was the exact issue.